# Updating Image file in database using MS Access

Tags: vb.net, image, ms-access, ms-access-2007, updating

Here is my code

```
    Dim Cmd As New OleDbCommand

    Dim strsql As String

    Try
        Dim fsreader As New FileStream(OpenFile.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim breader As New BinaryReader(fsreader)
        Dim imgbuffer(fsreader.Length) As Byte
        breader.Read(imgbuffer, 0, fsreader.Length)
        fsreader.Close()

        strsql = "UPDATE AccResult SET (PicFile, PicName) Values (@pfile, @pname) WHERE StudNo = '" & Form1.sNo.Text & "'"
        Cmd = New OleDbCommand(strsql, con)
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pfile", txtSave.Text)
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pname", imgbuffer)
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Cmd.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

please help me how can i update the students data when saving their picture in database. im using VB.NET. Thank You.

Comment: if I am not mistaken, that code is to change/update students' pictures. then load it again after saving. the `DataReader` thing..

Comment: yes sir.how can i update??

Comment: i already fixed the error sir :)

Comment: good for you. It will help others if you could answer your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like simple error in your logic - you have the filename reversed with the file content

```
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pfile", txtSave.Text)
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pname", imgbuffer)
```

Should be

```
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pfile", imgbuffer)
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pname", txtSave.Text)
```